# Find the percentage that two columns are equal but for each grouping variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out the number of times ordre_ou and Rank are both equal to 3. I would then want to put that number over the number of times ordre_ou and rank aren't equal to eachother (one or the other equals 3, but the other value is a 1 or 2). But, what makes this difficult is that sometimes ordre_ou = 9. When it equals nine, this basically means "NA". So, if for example ordre_ou = 9 but rank = 3, that doesn't tell me anything. I would want to count that ID in the equation.

I know this is a confusing situation so I'll explain more if needed. Basically, ordre_ou is what is correct in the field and rank is what the computer calculated for the size of the eggs. I'm trying to see the percentage that the field work matches up with the computer. Everything should be grouped by ID.

```
dput(head(test, n= 100))


structure(list(ordre_ou = c("9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "3", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "1", "2", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "1", "2", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "1", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"3", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "3", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "3", "9", 
"9", "9"), ID = c(65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 201L, 201L, 
201L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 492L, 492L, 492L, 566L, 566L, 670L, 670L, 
704L, 704L, 704L, 753L, 753L, 753L, 784L, 784L, 784L, 819L, 819L, 
819L, 899L, 899L, 978L, 978L, 978L, 1060L, 1060L, 1060L, 1085L, 
1085L, 1085L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1235L, 1235L, 1235L, 1245L, 
1245L, 1269L, 1269L, 1269L, 1355L, 1355L, 1355L, 1356L, 1398L, 
1398L, 1398L, 1432L, 1432L, 1432L, 1458L, 1458L, 1458L, 1485L, 
1485L, 1485L, 1495L, 1495L, 1495L, 1505L, 1505L, 1505L, 1547L, 
1547L, 1547L, 1647L, 1647L, 1647L, 1657L, 1657L, 1688L, 1688L, 
1689L, 1689L, 1689L, 1698L, 1698L, 1708L, 1708L, 1708L, 1788L, 
1788L, 1788L, 1818L, 1818L, 1818L), PVC = c("2JA", "2JA", "2JA", 
"2JA", "378", "378", "378", "6180113", "6180113", "6180113", 
"6C9", "6C9", "6C9", "ABBM", "ABBM", "ABBM", "ACAD", "ACAD", 
"ADHY", "ADHY", "AFA2", "AFA2", "AFA2", "AFWY", "AFWY", "AFWY", 
"AH62", "AH62", "AH62", "AHJZ", "AHJZ", "AHJZ", "ALX7", "ALX7", 
"AMNH", "AMNH", "AMNH", "AP1D", "AP1D", "AP1D", "APLV", "APLV", 
"APLV", "APWU", "APWU", "APWU", "AT0F", "AT0F", "AT0F", "AT4Y", 
"AT4Y", "AT9F", "AT9F", "AT9F", "AV09", "AV09", "AV09", "AV1H", 
"AVH3", "AVH3", "AVH3", "AVZ1", "AVZ1", "AVZ1", "AWJR", "AWJR", 
"AWJR", "AXWA", "AXWA", "AXWA", "AXZ8", "AXZ8", "AXZ8", "AY45", 
"AY45", "AY45", "AZTN", "AZTN", "AZTN", "BABH", "BABH", "BABH", 
"BAHF", "BAHF", "BBHW", "BBHW", "BBJ2", "BBJ2", "BBJ2", "BBR7", 
"BBR7", "BC48", "BC48", "BC48", "BLU4", "BLU4", "BLU4", "BMWZ", 
"BMWZ", "BMWZ"), volume = c(59.23784990144, 57.67430439496, 55.941075465885, 
48.404429520525, 67.157961538635, 64.8180845235, 63.97980996672, 
68.91794748218, 58.15209427632, 57.52472936967, 66.667141436785, 
64.58676156675, 64.023665822545, 65.69135053824, 64.95949243106, 
63.717349423605, 57.7816829604, 57.75826384494, 67.7353109265, 
67.722914861455, 59.107361578275, 53.6827574912, 52.437236559625, 
64.64865510559, 60.092046898125, 55.65314064794, 65.9105613504, 
62.9811246456, 61.480030107375, 68.98102287872, 64.97415691434, 
62.0186388864, 63.249484535685, 62.914807201085, 60.94741873068, 
59.17492867088, 56.411384122335, 63.2272234135, 62.956485644075, 
59.157746675305, 57.32597558688, 55.434329712945, 54.3981319965, 
62.651453886945, 62.577372119625, 62.2632710628, 68.695014093745, 
64.7600712, 62.976206042835, 58.64841651305, 52.945914427435, 
64.2293729965, 60.22368881416, 60.125075029525, 67.72683495592, 
67.22997541, 60.662151860875, 60.95034911232, 67.22828506375, 
66.915609213375, 60.36643261348, 62.80147116288, 61.349764975875, 
56.381856553125, 65.138343264, 63.83578172832, 63.70508488183, 
65.374179521625, 64.57772389536, 61.54970130264, 68.11689275854, 
67.19495722272, 62.6687671468, 52.671580238965, 52.6496500866, 
49.0571970612, 65.35484747352, 62.99067352736, 56.28804189684, 
62.95487917906, 62.3909914575, 60.54756491358, 65.748093606, 
54.28226780316, 62.28287596851, 58.394627784, 58.54877398376, 
58.236602452875, 55.7946013138, 62.92579837536, 52.510981991085, 
69.18252370636, 67.45773857636, 56.322131567625, 60.486013583465, 
57.9529663461, 56.943494213215, 58.03166940876, 52.74560792151, 
51.3303436), rank = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3), Year = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    PVC = c("2JA", "378", "6180113", "6C9", "ABBM", "ACAD", "ADHY", 
    "AFA2", "AFWY", "AH62", "AHJZ", "ALX7", "AMNH", "AP1D", "APLV", 
    "APWU", "AT0F", "AT4Y", "AT9F", "AV09", "AV1H", "AVH3", "AVZ1", 
    "AWJR", "AXWA", "AXZ8", "AY45", "AZTN", "BABH", "BAHF", "BBHW", 
    "BBJ2", "BBR7", "BC48", "BLU4", "BMWZ"), Year = c("2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:7, 
        8:10, 11:13, 14:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:23, 24:26, 27:29, 
        30:32, 33:34, 35:37, 38:40, 41:43, 44:46, 47:49, 50:51, 
        52:54, 55:57, 58L, 59:61, 62:64, 65:67, 68:70, 71:73, 
        74:76, 77:79, 80:82, 83:84, 85:86, 87:89, 90:91, 92:94, 
        95:97, 98:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -36L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: `sum(test$ordre_ou == 3 & test$rank == 3)` will give you the number of times they both match.  You can then get the inverse with `sum(!(test$ordre_ou == 3 & test$rank == 3))` which is when both do NOT match. I am a bit confused with the 9 being NA. Did you wan't this to be counted or not?

Comment: @brendbech if ordre_ou = 9, i don't want it to be counted at all. But, I can't necessarily filter out for when ordre_ou = 9 because sometimes only 2 of the values per ID will be 9. For example ordre_ou could be 9, 9, 3 and rank could be 1, 2, 3. I would want to count that one! but if it is 9, 1, 9 and rank is 1, 2, 3 I wouldn't want to count this since ordre_ou = 9 and rank = 3

Comment: I see. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, you will get the count of matching, not matching and total with a percentage column saying the correct percentage rate. I've added a commented line for filtering out rows where ordre_ou is equal to 9 as i was not completely sure what you meant by this being like `NA`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  #filter(ordre_ou != 9) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    correct = sum(ordre_ou == 3 & rank == 3),
    wrong = sum(!(ordre_ou == 3 & rank == 3)),
    total = n()
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    perc = correct/total
  )
```